# error in django of -- MultiValueDictKeyError at /signup

Tags: django, django-views

i create a simple login and signup project but at the signup process when i sign up and redirect to the login page i got the error called "MultiValueDictKeyError"
this is my **signup.html** file -->

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>sign up here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Sign Up</h3>
    <form action="/signup" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="">username</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Create a user name" Required><br>
        <label for="">first name</label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fmyname" placeholder="First Name" Required><br>
        <label for="">last name</label>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" Required><br>
        <label for="">email</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="enter your email address" Required><br>
        <label for="">password</label>
        <input type="password" id="pass1" name="pass" placeholder="enter your password" Required><br>
        <label for="">re-enter password</label>
        <input type="password" id="pass2" name="pass2" placeholder="re enter your password" Required><br><br>

        <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is **views.py**

```
def signup(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        # username = request.POST.get('username')
        username = request.POST['username']
        firsname = request.POST['fmyname']     #here i got ERROR of the multivaluedictkeyerror
        lname = request.POST['lname']
        email = request.POST['email']
        pass1 = request.POST['pass']
        pass2 = request.POST['pass2']

        myuser = User.objects.create_user(username, email, pass1)

        myuser.first_name = firsname
        myuser.last_name = lname

        myuser.save()

        messages.success(request, "your account is created.")
        return redirect('signin')

    return render(request, 'authentication\signup.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

========= change you code with it ========

```
if request.method == "POST":
        # username = request.POST.get('username')
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        firsname = request.POST.get('fmyname')
        lname = request.POST.get('lname')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        pass1 = request.POST.get('pass')
        pass2 = request.POST.get('pass2')

        myuser = User.objects.create_user(username, email, pass1)

        myuser.first_name = firsname
        myuser.last_name = lname

        myuser.save()

        messages.success(request, "your account is created.")
        return redirect('signin')
```

Comment: still it get's error -> IntegrityError at /signup
UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username     -- myuser = User.objects.create_user(username, email, pass1)  "at this line"

Comment: it's error for username already exist in database try with another username

Comment: according to you  where should i change it name.

Comment: delete user record from user table and try to insert new record

Comment: still won't work brother. also i changed name as a user_name

Comment: live:.cid.c0953c9365350c64  send me your code skype

Comment: sorry for your inconvenience but i don't have skype i got you this link ( https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18mXx7B-rDYwvjz_bYdLEBmLex30Qe8FS?usp=sharing ) i have this drive link if you need skype i can send you.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jw2MM2zaNCDEMuFKwx02stGpRi2cWDY0/view?usp=sharing

please read Readme file 

and I also put all auth system code in the [ Django Auth ] folder which is in your project directory 

please correct my answer of stackowerflow